# Flutter - Determine time to go to sleep with hour i want to wake up

Tags: datetime, flutter, dart

I'm new to Dart and Flutter and i am looking for some help. I'm trying to do this :

-The user pick a hour and minute in a Cupertino date picker (it's hour he want to wake up in the morning)

-I would like to determine the exact time he need to go to sleep to have 7 hour of good sleeping.

*(This function is working but i can't figurate how to add minutes to hour and then determine the right calculation)*

```
void Bed(int Heure, int Minute) {

    if (Heure - Cycle <= 0) {
      result = Heure - Cycle + 24;

    } else {

      result = Heure - Cycle;
    }
  }
```

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I would just only calculate in minutes. So take your hours*60 , do you calculation with only minutes, and then convert back to hours in the end.

```
  double total = 140; //Your total time converted to minutes

  double mins = total % 60; //your minutes

  double hrs = (total - mins) / 60; // your hours

  print(mins);
  print(hrs);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!

I am not confortable with it but i finally figurate it out !